# How to refresh Angular application based on DB changes

Tags: angular

I have a Frontend Angular application, connected to its own Backend API.
The backend is a dotnet application subscribed to events sent to an Event Bus by other external applications.

When events are received, some entities in backend DB are created/updated.

I want to reflect those changes in the frontend. It doesn't need to be necessarily real-time.

The only solutions that come to my mind are:

1. refreshing data in the Angular app by calling backend API at scheduled intervals
2. websockets...?

I don't understand if 1. is a viable solution or if 2. is too difficult to implement or if there are other options.

The data shown will be mainly tables of data rows.

Comment: Using websockets should be relatively easy with rxjs: [webSocket](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket). Since you are using Angular, you are probably already familiar with rxjs.

Comment: 1. Is a common way and called polling. There is short polling and long polling. 2. Is the modern way and probably more intuitive.

Comment: Looks like a one way communication, basically just a note from BE that something has changed. I would suggest using SSE in this case.